# Cross compile arm assembly for x86

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, x86, arm, clang

I have an ARM assembly file (test.s) on a linux x86 computer.

I would like to compile and run this file on the linux box, but I'm not sure how.

Do I need to use clang? If so, what is the command?

Comment: How big is the assembly file? Hand-written or generated? If generated, can't you ask whoever generated it in the first place to generate an equivalent one for Intel x86? The instructions sets are quite different between ARM and x86. If it's hand-written, you'd probably have to rewrite it, because see above.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev The file in question is hand-written and not very large. I was trying to find a solution which would be re-usable for larger files in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's highly unlikely that clang is going to help you in any way. Clang is a C/C++ compiler after all.

What you need is an assembly translator. Such things do exist, but when open source projects are concerned, the quality is rather varying, so you should just google it and see for yourself.

LLVM (the machine abstraction library below clang) had been used to do such things. Using LLVM is not different from using any other assembly translator: first you map your arm assembly to LLVM assembly, then you can compile LLVM assembly into something else.

An example of such project is outlined here: http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/149975/files/x86-llvm-translator-chipounov_2.pdf. This team was using a specially patched QEMU to produce intermediate LLVM code for them.

In most such cases, it is easier (and safer) to simply rewrite the assembly by hand, possibly into higher level language.

If the assembly file in question is a stand-alone program, you may not need to translate it at all. Simply try QEMU (http://www.qemu.org).